# Андроид. Как реализовать добавление в избранное

Tags: java, android, listview

Здравствуйте! Подскажите как можно реализовать добавление избранное и удаление?

Есть два активити. В главном активити `MainActivity` реализован вывод списка `ListView`, при нажатии на пункт списка открывается второе активити с полным текстом.
Так вот во втором активити я добавил `FloatingActionButton`, при нажатии на него статья будет добавляться в избранное. 
Но как это реализовать я не совсем понимаю. Может кто знает, хотя бы подскажите направление в каком нужно двигаться.

Полный код:

Актитивити со спискам `MainActivity`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    // получаем экземпляр элемента ListView
    ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
    TextView textV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textV);

    // определяем массив типа String
    // заголовки в списке
    final String[] catnames = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.cat_names);

    // текст выводиться во втором активити
    final String[] catnames2 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.cat_names2);
    // второй текст для второго активити
    final String[] catnames3 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.cat_names3);

    // используем адаптер данных
    final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.item, catnames);

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    // массив количество элементов
    final int[] mice = new int [catnames.length];

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View itemClicked, int position,long id) {
            TextView textView = (TextView) itemClicked;
            String strText = textView.getText().toString(); // получаем текст нажатого элемента

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ((TextView) itemClicked).getText(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            for(int x=0;x<catnames.length;x++){
                mice[x]=x; // заполняем массив
                System.out.println(mice[x]); // выводим массив в цикле
                if (strText == catnames[x]) {
                    // Запускаем активность, связанную с определенным именем кота
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LastActivity.class);
                    // для отправки в другой класс. Ключ и значение(то что в поле editText)
                    intent.putExtra("name1", catnames[x]);
                    intent.putExtra("name2", catnames2[x]);
                    intent.putExtra("name3", catnames3[x]);
                    startActivity(intent);

                }
            }
        }
    });

}

}
```

Второе активити для полного текста `LastActivity` с кнопкой `FloatingActionButton` для добавление в избранное

```
public class LastActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView textView;
TextView textView2;
TextView textView3;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_last);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);



    // находим в коде
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    textView3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);

    // получаем Intent извликаем из него объект
    Intent intent = getIntent();

    // извлекаем из него объект
    String name1 = intent.getStringExtra("name1");
    String name2 = intent.getStringExtra("name2");
    String name3 = intent.getStringExtra("name3");

    // выводим полученные данные
    textView.setText(name1);
    textView2.setText(name2);
    textView3.setText(name3);

    // кнопка добавить в избранное
    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Добавлена в избранное", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно по разному.

Например сохраняйте к-л идентификатор в sharedPreferences. После этого, в списке, проверяйте его наличие и отображайте в списке нужным образом статус

Comment: Не совсем понял. К примеру я сохранил некоторые пункты в sharedPreferences, и как их вывести?? 
Есть ли в ListView какой нибудь фильтр.
Например при нажатии на пункт меню из sharedPreferences добавлялись бы в фильтр эти числа, и выводился бы не весь ListView, а только с этими числами???

Comment: @Artsait, вообще есть у ListView фильтры, но гораздо проще самостоятельно сформировать список данных по заданному условию

Comment: Все равно не доходит. Вы имеете ввиду с помощью ListView.add добавлять пункты?

Ладно я попробую новый вопрос задать, может там будет более понятно, что у меня не получается. В любом случае спасибо))